# Problem setting DataSource of a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

What happens here is when in the form opens, it shows the contextMenu and display the DataGridView on it with the value of dataSet1. But when I click the button to change the DataSource of the Grid, it doesn't show the records of dataSet2.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetDataSource(dataSet1);// A populated DataSet
}

protected void SetDataSource(DataSet ds)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
    ToolStripControlHost tsHost = new ToolStripControlHost(dataGridView1);
    contextMenuStrip1.Items.Clear();
    contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(tsHost);
    contextMenuStrip1.Show(textBox1, 0, 27);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetDataSource(dataSet2);// Another populated DataSet
}
```

I tried adding another DataGridView control (dataGridView2) in my form, but this time I did not put it in a ToolStripControlHost and I did not add it to the contextMenuStrip1.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView2.DataSource = ds; // <-- Parent of this is the Form1, the control is not added in the contextMenuStrip.
ToolStripControlHost tsHost = new ToolStripControlHost(dataGridView1);
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Clear();
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(tsHost);
contextMenuStrip1.Show(textBox1, 0, 27);
```

When the Form1 loads, the contextMenuStrip1 popups and the dataGridView1 is being added as an item to it making dataGridView1 to disappear in the form and the dataGridView2 only remains in the Form1.

When I hit the `button1` the `dataGridView2` changes its content base from its new `DataSource` (`dataSet2`), while the dataGridView1 still displays the value of `dataSet1`.
What I noticed is when the time `dataGridView1` is being added to the `ToolStripHost`, and make it an Item in the `contextMenuStrip1`, the `DataSource` property of the `DataGridView` control is not being changed anymore. Unlike the `dataGridView2` that remains in the form which I did not add to the `contextMenuStrip1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me a while, but I found it. Controls in a `ToolStripControlHost` don't seem to get assigned the `BindingContext` carried through a regular control tree.

You can take care of this yourself by adding the following to the first line of your `SetDataSource` method:

```
dataGridView1.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
```

For fair attribution, I got the idea from [this web page](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms/topic54247.aspx), where a similar situation was encountered with respect to a ComboBox. I tested it out in a sample app with your code to verify it works.

Comment: Nice. But what's the concept behind this, i.e. behind the behavior?

Comment: @TheBlastOne Excellent question. I do not know why the BindingContext is not inherited; I simply accepted the work-around as sufficient. Cheers!

Answer (score -3):

Just changing the datasource of a control does not tell it to re-bind(refresh) its data from that new datasource.  You need to execute the control's DataBind() command after you change its datasource.

So after this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

try adding this:

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, DataGridView control has no DataBind property. But GridView has in ASP.Net